# Rule to Change Webform Submission to Draft

Tags: rules, webforms

I'm looking for a way with Rules (or otherwise I just figured that Rules would be the easiest without writing custom modules), to change the submission status of a webform from Submitted, to Draft.

Basically, I have a form that a user submits but doesn't have access to a yes/no question.  Based on a custom module, another user will have access to edit that submission and answer the yes/no question.

If that answer is no, I want to change the status of the webform from submitted, to draft so that the initial user will easily see that they need to make changes and the emails will fire again once they resubmit the form.

So in summary:
I have a form with Field A and B that gets submitted by User A who only has access to Field A.  Once that form is submitted, User B has access to the submission and can change the value of Field B, then save the submission (Rule: when a Webform submission is updated).  Depending on the value of Field B, I want to change the completed status of the webform back to it being in Draft status.

Thanks!

Module/Core info:

Drupal 7

Webform 4.16

Webform Rules 1.6

Rules 2.10

Comment: Was the summary a sufficient edit?